# Записать значения булевого массива в модель C#

Tags: c#

Стоит задача следующего характера. Создал класс - модель действий:

```
public class ActionModel
{
    public bool On { get; set; }
    public bool Off { get; set; }
    public bool Kitchen { get; set; }
    public bool Audio { get; set; }
    public bool Heat { get; set; }
    public bool Camera { get; set; }
    public bool Lights { get; set; }
    public bool CeilingLights { get; set; }
}
```

Методы для конвертации данных:

```
private static byte ConvertBoolArrayToByte(bool[] source)
{
    byte result = 0;
    int index = 8 - source.Length;

    foreach (bool b in source)
    {
        if (b)
            result |= (byte)(1 << (7 - index));

        index++;
    }
    return result;
}

private static bool[] ConvertByteToBoolArray(byte b)
{
    bool[] result = new bool[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        result[i] = (b & (1 << i)) == 0 ? false : true;

    Array.Reverse(result);

    return result;
}
```

И в `Main` я устанавливаю значения в конструкторе экземпляра:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ActionModel model = new ActionModel()
    {
        On = true,
        Off = false,
        Audio = true,
        Camera = true,
        CeilingLights = false,
        Heat = false,
        Kitchen = false
    };

    // Читаю данные из модели в булевый массив
    var type = typeof(ActionModel);
    bool[] boolProperties = type
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
        .Select(p => (bool)p.GetGetMethod().Invoke(model, null)).ToArray();

    foreach (var r in boolProperties)
    {
        Console.Write($"{r} ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:X}", ConvertBoolArrayToByte(boolProperties)));
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertBoolArrayToByte(boolProperties));

    Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++");

    var res = ConvertByteToBoolArray(ConvertBoolArrayToByte(boolProperties));

    foreach (var r in res)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r);
    }

    // Как записать массив булей в модель?

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Получается, что я могу выставить значения в модель. После чего прочитать в массив. А вот как потом булевый массив присвоить конкретным полям модели?
В голову приходит, создать метод, где просто присваивать по индексу, правильно ли это?

```
private static void Set(ActionModel model, bool[] res)
{
    model.On = res[0];
    model.Audio = res[1];
    model.CeilingLights = res[2];
    //и тд...
}
```

Comment: Я думаю, что вам стоит смотреть в сторону сериализации всего объекта в массив байт. к тому же это позволит вам отказаться от неуместной тут рефлексии

Comment: Почему не использовать встроенную в BCL коллекцию `BitArray`? И еще обратите внимание на этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/560131/6766879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
public class ActionModel
{
    public bool On { get => get(0); set => set(0, value); }
    public bool Off { get => get(1); set => set(1, value); }
    public bool Kitchen { get => get(2); set => set(2, value); }
    public bool Audio { get => get(3); set => set(3, value); }  
    public bool Heat { get => get(4); set => set(4, value); }
    public bool Camera { get => get(5); set => set(5, value); }
    public bool Lights { get => get(6); set => set(6, value); }
    public bool CeilingLights { get => get(7); set => set(7, value); }

    private bool[] store = new bool[8];
    private bool get(int i) => store[i];
    private bool set(int i, bool v) => store[i] = v;

    public ActionModel() {}
    private ActionModel(bool[] array) {this.store = array;}

    public static bool[] ConvertToBoolArray(ActionModel model)
    {
        var res = new bool[model.store.Length];
        Array.Copy(model.store, res, model.store.Length);
        return res;     
    }

    public static ActionModel ConvertFromBoolArray(bool[] source)
    {
        var res = new bool[source.Length];
        Array.Copy(source, res, source.Length);
        return new ActionModel(res);
    }
}
```

Как использовать:

```
var model = new ActionModel() {Audio = true};
var array = ActionModel.ConvertToBoolArray(model);
var newModel = ActionModel.ConvertFromBoolArray(array);
Console.WriteLine(newModel.Audio);
```

**UPD**

Как использовать с базовым классом

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    protected bool[] store = new bool[0];
    protected bool get(int i) => store[i];
    protected bool set(int i, bool v) => store[i] = v;  

    public bool[] ConvertToFlags()
    {
        var res = new bool[this.store.Length];
        Array.Copy(this.store, res, this.store.Length);
        return res;
    }

    public void InitFromFlags(bool[] source)
    {
        var res = new bool[source.Length];
        Array.Copy(source, res, source.Length);
        this.store = res;
    }
}
```

Модель

```
public class ActionModel : BaseModel
{
    public bool On { get => get(0); set => set(0, value); }
    public bool Off { get => get(1); set => set(1, value); }
    public bool Kitchen { get => get(2); set => set(2, value); }
    public bool Audio { get => get(3); set => set(3, value); }
    public bool Heat { get => get(4); set => set(4, value); }
    public bool Camera { get => get(5); set => set(5, value); }
    public bool Lights { get => get(6); set => set(6, value); }
    public bool CeilingLights { get => get(7); set => set(7, value); }

    public ActionModel() { this.store = new bool[8]; }
}
```

Пример использования

```
var model = new ActionModel() {Audio = true};
var array = model.ConvertToFlags();
var newModel = new ActionModel();
newModel.InitFromFlags(array);  
Console.WriteLine(newModel.Audio);
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!  Скажите, а вот можно методы дженериками сделать, что бы разные модели скармливать?

Comment: @JDo как вы это представляете? да и зачем генерики?

Comment: Хотел методы обобщеные, что бы в разных моделях не дублировать.

Comment: Если вам нужен универсальный метод для конвертации модели в массив байт, то вам тогда точно нужна бинарная сериализация. То, что я показал, просто конвертит структуру флагов в массив флагов.

Comment: Получается сериализовать через BinnaryFormatter с использованием memorystream?

Comment: @JDo да, через него

Comment: Сериализую я свою модель, но вернуть смогу все равно ту же модель а не массив булевых свойств. Сериализую то я его в массив байт. Ваш ответ как раз решал эту проблему очень хорошо! Единственное, у меня могут быть от двух до нескольких моделей по 8 свойств. Просто не хочется дублировать методы конвертирования в каждой модели.

Comment: @JDo а если засунуть эти методы в базовый класс ваших моделей?

Comment: Что-то вроде такого? ` public abstract class BaseModel
    {
        public abstract bool[] ConvertToBoolArray<T>(T model);

        public abstract T ConvertFromBoolArray<T>(bool[] source);
    }`

Comment: @JDo да, что то типа того, хотя для `ConvertFromBoolArray` все равно придется прописывать в каждой модели как её создавать из флагов.

Comment: @JDo обновил ответ

Comment: Огонь! Спасибо за помощь!